# Use getIdToken as Authorization token for Google Sheet API

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-sheets, google-api

I am trying to make a call to:
`https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/GOOGLE_SHEET_ID:batchUpdate`

as in:

```js
fetch(
      `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/GOOGLE_SHEET_ID:batchUpdate`,
      {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${bearerToken}`,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          requests: [
            {
              repeatCell: {
                range: {
                  startColumnIndex: 0,
                  endColumnIndex: 1,
                  startRowIndex: 0,
                  endRowIndex: 1,
                  sheetId: 0,
                },
                cell: {
                  userEnteredValue: {
                    numberValue: 10,
                  },
                },
                fields: "*",
              },
            },
          ],
        }),
      }
    );
```

I am trying to use firebase auth to get the bearer token as follows:

```js
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        user.getIdToken().then(token => setBearerToken(token))
    }
 });
```

The problem is that using that token I get this response (yes I checked that the bearerToken is properly set):

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

Is the Id Token valid? How can I get the appropiate Access Token from Firebase Auth?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call the google sheets API, then you need to get access token from the Google Authorization server. Is firebase indirectly getting the bearer token from the Google Authorization server ? Secondly, bearer token and ID token are two separate concepts. Oauth ID Token is used to get information about User but access token can be passed to Resource API. I suspect that you are passing a totally unrelated token to the API.